# Part of fee not transferring to other account

Tags: solidity

I am transferring part of fee to another wallet by this code

```
   uint256 perc = 0;
  
  perc = (msg.value * aComm1) / 100;
  address(uint160(_s1)).transfer(perc);
```

while this code running perfectly in testnet, fee percent is transferring it is not working in Mainnet. I am using solidity >=0.5.10;.

_s1 contains valid address, aComm1 has value of 15

Comment: the only reason for transfer to fail is the lack of funds

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. You should verify that the call indeed is sending ETH with it. You should also be aware that since decimals aren't a thing in solidity, `perc` will be `0` if `msg.value < 7` due to truncation

Comment: thank you very much for kind comments, funds are there, fee value is 0.01 BNB, and perc is working very good for small amounts in remix also and in testnet also, pretty strange for me as I was confident after >10 transactions in testnet and it is still working there. Also I can see that the portion of the fee is missing from contract balance, means that value is going somewhere but not in desired address

Comment: @natewelch_ seems you got the point, I am sending fee multiplied by 1e18 from webjs and providing 15 as percent from write contract on bscscan. While checking on tenderly I am getting perc = 1 instead of 0.15